# SEVERE: ConnectionStrategyFailed with Apache TomEE

Tags: ejb, apache-tomee, openejb

Can someone tell me if they encountered this error

```
SEVERE: ConnectionStrategyFailed{strategy=StickyConnectionStrategy, cluster=org.apache.openejb.client.ClusterMetaData@2a3046da, server=http-remoting://localhost:8080}
```

And if yes what did you do to resolve it?

I tried researching on it but so far I have not found anything to resolve it.

Comment: Imho best to write a mail to the user list.